# cannot start android's emulator camera on a mac

Tags: android, android-emulator

am using a mac lion with android 4.0 sdk. Whenever I want to start the camera on the emulator, I encounter "android camera unexpected jpeg encoding quality levels 0" error. I have set camera support in the avd manager. I do not have this problem on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the latest sdk tools and they will come with a configure camera options.`